# Javascript/Express - Exports all methods vs exporting class containing methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am confused while encountering this over-looked question like how they are different ?

```js
Module.exports = {
  search_companies(req, res) {
    //some ops
  },

  get_details(req, res) {
    //some ops
  }
};
```

vs

```js
class MainContrller {

  search_companies(req, res) {
      //some ops
    },

    get_details(req, res) {
      //some ops
    }
}

module.exports.MainController = MainController;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one exports an object with the function `search_companies` and `get_details`. So you can call these to function on the object that is exported.

The second one exports a class `MainController` with the functions `search_companies` and `get_details`. Here you have to create an instance of `MainController` to be able to call those two functions on the instance.

You use the first syntax if you only need one instance of that object through the whole project. It's like a singleton or like static, but without the need to define an actual class for it.

And you use the second one if you need multiple different instances of `MainController`.

Answer (score 0):

A module is supposed to be used like:

```
const { search_companies } = require('...');
```

A class is supposed to be used like:

```
const { MainController } = require('...');
const { search_companies } = new MainController();
```

`MainController` in this case is a bad practice because it mimics the usage of classes in other languages without taking the specifics of JavaScript into account.

`MainController` doesn't benefit from being a class if `this` instance is ignored and doesn't lose in functionality when a class is refactored to separate functions.

Classes aren't glorified namespaces in JavaScript; there are modules that already serve this purpose. If there's a need for a namespace and no need for class instance, a module can be used as a rule of thumb.